# Setting sparse=True in Scikit Learn OneHotEncoder does not reduce memory usage

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset that consists of 85 feature columns and 13195 rows. Approximately 50 of these features are categorical features which I encoded using OneHotEncoder. I was reading this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/working-with-sparse-data-sets-in-pandas-and-sklearn-d26c1cfbe067) about sparse data sets and was intrigued to see how changing the value of the sparse parameter when defining a OneHotEncoder object may reduce memory usage for my dataset.

Before applying OneHotEncoding to categorical features in my dataset, I have a **memory usage of 9.394 MB**. I found this by running this code:

```py
    BYTES_TO_MB_DIV = 0.000001
    def print_memory_usage_of_data_frame(df):
        mem = round(df.memory_usage().sum() * BYTES_TO_MB_DIV, 3) 
        print("Memory usage is " + str(mem) + " MB")
        
    print_memory_usage_of_data_frame(dataset)
```

Setting OneHotEncoder spare=True:

```py
    from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
    
    
    numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('knnImputer', KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2, weights="uniform")),
        ('scaler', StandardScaler())])
    
    categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
        ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=True))])
    
    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, selector(dtype_exclude="object")),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, selector(dtype_include="object"))
    ])
    
      
    Z = pd.DataFrame(preprocessor.fit_transform(X))
    print_memory_usage_of_data_frame(Z)
```

**Memory usage is 25.755 MB**

Then running the same code above but setting spare=False like so:

```py
    OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
```

**Memory usage is 25.755 MB**

According to the linked article, which used the sparse option in pandas get_dummies, this should result in reduced memory storage, is this not the same for Scikit Learn's OneHotEncoder?

Comment: It may be because of the numeric portion.  Try just the encoder (or just dropping the numeric pipeline from the `ColumnTransformer`), and try changing the `sparse_threshold` parameter of the `ColumnTransformer`.

Comment: I don't think `Pandas` `SparseArray` format is compatible with `OneHotEncoder` sparse matrix format (it's `scipy.sparse` format I think). And I think you should not use `Pandas` at the end of the process, you should use it to read and wrangle `csv` files, but don't use it after scaling and transforming data, it will eat up a lot of memory.

Comment: Thanks @BenReiniger, I removed the numeric portion and the memory usage went down to 0.106 MB. I tied changing the sparse_threshold=0.5 instead of the default 0.3 but it did not change the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @BenReiniger's comment, I removed the numeric portion from the ColumnTransformer and ran the following code:

```py
    from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
    
    
    categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
        ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=True))])
    
    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, selector(dtype_include="object"))
    ])
    
      
    X = pd.DataFrame(preprocessor.fit_transform(X))
    
    print_memory_usage_of_data_frame(X)
```

The result was **Memory usage is 0.106 MB**,

Running the same code above but with sparse option set to False:

```py
    OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
```

resulted in **Memory usage is 20.688 MB**.

So it is clear that changing the sparse parameter in OneHotEncoder does indeed reduce memory usage.

Comment: Where does `print_memory_usage_of_data_frame()` come from?

Comment: @elevendollar it is a function I defined, you can find it in my question above.

Comment: Oh, of course. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks!